# Enum relating to a string array that was read from file

Tags: java, arrays, string, enums

I've received a working code (in Java, 1.7) that does the following:
load an array of strings (a list of blood test names) from a file into a string array member (using Properties and FileInputStream). The file can change the strings but the meaning stays the same (for example: a test can be called "abc" and in another run it is called "zzz"). I've got an enum class that enumerates the test names. The enum strings aren't the same as the inputted strings (since the latter can change).

file bloodtest.names contains:

```
bloodTestNames=abc;def;123;
```

code:

```
public enum BloodTestNames {
AAA,BBB,CCC;    
}

Properties props = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("bloodtest.names");
props.load(fis);
String testName[]=props.getProperty("bloodTestNames").toString().split(";");
```

Now to the questions:
Question 1:
I need to return the string that was set in the file when I know the test name (for instance: return "def" for value BBB). What's the best of doing that?

the best way I've come up with is:

```
return testName[BloodTestNames.BBB.ordinal()]
```

Question 2: if BBB is not known in compile time - how do I accomplish the same target?

Three points:
* I'm a veteran at C but a newbie with Java. Any Do's and Don't are welcome. Assume my Java knowledge is zero.
* I don't total re-factoring is that's what's needed here.
* I've probably forgot to mention important details, please ask and I'll feel the missing gaps

Comment: Given the fact that the values are read from the file, the number of options would change, but the enum values will remain constant. You should not enum in this case. Can you please let us know why u chose enums?

Comment: "(using Properties and FileInputStream)" <-- uh, why both?

Comment: @sidgate: the choice of enums was so the code would be the same no matter what the actual string would be. How would you solve this problem (with or without enum). Main goal is for code to be readable and main-tenable.

Comment: @fge: I've used an example I saw (can't seem to find it now...)

Comment: @DrorCohen, [I owe you one](https://github.com/fge/msg-simple/commit/82db7d4d8c69d40b8b28e4878d363d6773ec73ef) (for whatever definition of "one")

Comment: @fge: definition of "one": +1 the question and/or answer it ;-)

Comment: Using enums here is just *horribly* wrong. You could just identify blood tests by they order (number indexes in array created by `split` method)

Comment: Using enums to represent what ought to be a look-up table in a database is feasible.  But I have to ask myself why you would want to maintain an in-code lookup table when instead you could ... oh, say ... use a database to hold a lookup table.  If the table is frequently accessed and performance critical you could probably justify the code-maintenance of updating a massive enum with frequent recompiling of code.  Otherwise, you get a more memory-friendly and flexible solution by putting your lookup table into a lookup table.

Comment: @scottb: The natural answer to your question is that you can't avoid recompiling if each entry in the lookup table has its own custom *logic* -- which means you need Java code for it, not merely some properties which can be set in a database.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu: Agreed.  However, if we're not talking about static data at any level, then we shouldn't even be talking about enums in the first place.

Comment: @scottb: indeed; and I tried to make this as clear as I could in my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first assume you do need enum constants for modeling this use-case because you have some sort of specific code to be executed for each kind of blood test (otherwise, a simple set of strings would be enough and more flexible, since you don't need to know the number of tests upfront or care about their names).

---

Q1: Since Java enums are a little more than a sequence of values, you can make full use of their object oriented nature.

```
public enum BloodTest {
    AAA, BBB, CCC;

    private static String[] names;

    public static void setNames(String[] names) {
        if (BloodTest.names != null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("You can only set the names once");
        if (names.length != values().length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of names");
        BloodTest.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return names[ordinal()];
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is to initialize your enum by calling `BloodTest.setNames(namesFromConfiguration)` and then you can get the string representation of each constant by calling the standard `toString()` method on it: `BloodTest.BBB.toString()`.

Since the initial assumption was that you have some specific logic for each of the test types, I would suggest that logic (as well as the required properties) will also be encapsulated in the enum itself or the enum constants; e.g.:

```
public enum BloodTest {
    AAA(10) {
        @Override
        public boolean isRequired(MedicalRecord medicalRecord) {
            return medicalRecord.includes("someDisease");
        }
    },
    BBB(15) {
        @Override
        public boolean isRequired(MedicalRecord medicalRecord) {
            return ! medicalRecord.hasTakenBloodTestsLately();
        }
    },
    CCC(20) { // ... also implements the abstract method and so on

    private final int threshold;

    private BloodTest(int threshold) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
    }

    public boolean hasPassed(int value) {
        return value <= threshold;
    }

    public abstract boolean isRequired(MedicalRecord medicalRecord);

    // ... same as above
}
```

Now, once you get a reference to some `BloodTest`, you can check whether that specific test passed by invoking the corresponding method without `switch`ing and having the logic spread around the client code:

```
BloodTest bloodTest = BloodTest.valueOf(someString); // someString can be "AAA", "BBB" or "CCC"
// no matter which constant this is, you use it as an object and rely on polymorphism
if (bloodTest.hasPassed(someValue)) { // ... do something
```

---

Q2: Your question 2 kind of "questions" my initial assumption regarding your actual need for an enum. If there's a chance you'll need to dynamically handle blood tests that you don't know about yet, then you can't use an enum.

In other words, if your code does not have any `switch` or `if/else if` blocks to handle each blood test, an enum is a really bad choice for your use case.

However, if it does, than I'd recommend refactoring the code to include the logic in the enum itself as in the above example, rather than in `switch`/`if` blocks; moreover, if your `switch` has a `default` case (or your `if` has a final `else` block), this can still be modeled in the enum itself, for instance by adding a `DEFAULT` constant as a fallback.

Comment: Trying to use your answer gets me a lot of "error: variable XXX might not have been initialized". First error is when I call BLoodTest.setNames(). Other places is where I try to use it in a loop: for(BloodTests bt: btn.values()) - what's the newbiew mistake I'm doing?

Comment: Please ignore my last comment... Trying to use your answer gets me a "error: variable XXX might not have been initialized". When I first call BLoodTest.setNames(). Do I need to declare a "statuc public BloodTest bt" and then call bt.setNames()? I thought since it's an Enum class I can just call BLoodTest.setNames() in my init code...

Comment: No, since it's a static method you need to call that on the enum type itself: `BloodTest.setNames(someNames)`. Does this raise an error ? My first guess would be your local variable `someNames` is not initialized; for instance, if you assign it in a `try` block and try to use it outside that block.

Answer (score 1):

Make the whole thing settings driven: Add a statuc method to load in settings of what string maps to what enum and add a factory method that uses these settings:

```
public enum BloodTestNames {
    AAA,BBB,CCC; 
    private static Map<String, BloodTestNames> map = new HashMap<String, BloodTestNames>();

    public static void addAlias(String alias, String name) {
        map.put(alias, valueOf(name));
    }

    public static BloodTestNames getByAluas(String alias) {
        if (map.containsKey(alias))
            return map.get(alias);
        // own name assumed to be mapped
        return valueOf(alias);
    }
}
```

On startup, repeatedly call `BloodTestNames.addAlias()` based on some settings file to load the mappings.

When you're reading the saved file, use `BloodTestNames.getByAlias()` to return the enum for a given string value.

---

You would do well to name your class in the singular, and drop "Name", ie `BloodTest` - name the class for what each enum is (all enums have a "name" which is the coded instance name).

Answer (score 0):

A short extract from one of my enum class :

```
public enum TypesStructurelsE {
    SOURCE("SRC"),
    COLONNE("COL");

    private String code;

    TypesStructurelsE(final String code1) {
        code = code1;
    }


    /** @return String */
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(final String newCode) {
        code = newCode;
    }
}
```

. . In other class

```
if(TypesStructurelsE.SOURCE.getCode().equal(testName[i])){ // can be "COL" or "SRC" 
//
;
}
```

... changing value :

```
TypesStructurelsE.SOURCE.setCode("SOURCE_NEW");
```

So, if your properties file change, you have just to compile with the new symbole (SRC --> SOURCE) no more

Comment: Is there a solution without recompiling? the different files stand for different clients so I want to be able to use same code with just different parameter files

Comment: Exact, I've forgot it, changed in my response - Thanks!